# Changing file encoding in Exchanger XML editor

Tags: html, xml

I have been searching for hours the file encoding settings for Exhanger XML editor, though no success. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing the encoding of an existing file:

```
XML Menu -> Set XML Declaration...
```

Not very intuitive, I think :)

Comment: Yes :)
In addition it doesn't provide ANSI encoding, which I am searching for. This tool starts annoying me...